# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'defaultView': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following script inside my asp.net mvc:-

```
function deleteconfirmation() {

    jAlert('The Answer was deleted succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); });

}
```

but when it is executed it will return the following error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'defaultView': object is null or undefined" on the `if(!(e=a.ownerDocument.defaultView))` inside the jquery-1.6.2.min.js.
Hint:- this error will only occur if i am using IE , it will not occur if i am using chrome or firefox!!!!
So what might be causing this ?
BR

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by your `$(this)` not referring to anything, or the `window object` rather. It depends on how your function is called. It's best to pass the element you want to use into the function `deleteConfirmation()` like so:

```
$("#deleteAnswer").bind("click", function() {
    deleteConfirmation(this);
});

function deleteConfirmation(element) {
    jAlert('Deleted succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation', function() {
        alert("The user clicked ok");

        // Hides the element that caused the click event
        $(element).fadeOut('slow', function () { $(element).remove(); });
    });
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHDPA/1/) for an example.

If you're trying to `fadeOut` the alert box itself, that is done by default, as you might already know.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have forget to add the Reference of the jQuery Library. Please check this and add to the [jQuery Reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

The other possibility is forgotting to add the Reference of jAlert in the page where you are using.